# Сдать положительный тест - ошибка или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость, лексикология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли сочетание "сдать положительный тест"? Ведь мы сдаем просто тест и получаем результат - положительный или отрицательный. Упорно не могу понять, как можно сдать положительный тест (вместо "получить положительный результат теста"), хотя вижу постоянно в СМИ. Или такое сочетание допустимо?

Comment: Увиденное имеет адрес? Источник укажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Если полностью исключить условности и компромиссы, направленные на упрощение высказывания, придётся отказаться и от выражения "сдать тест". "Сдают" *биологический материал*, тесты над которым проводят *специалисты*, а никак не "сдающие"; эти же специалисты **получают результат**, а сдающие материал (= проходящие тестирование на наличие возбудителя болезни) ***получают сведения** о результатах* теста (тестирования материала), а не сам результат. Поэтому выбор между исходным выражением и предложенным вами для замены может изменить только степень *формальности* выражения (ваш - более формальный и длинный). *Оба* варианта компромиссны (не ошибочны), поскольку строгая формулировка была бы излишне длинной.

Comment: Результат может быть абстрактным понятием, не лишь материальным. Так что "сдающие материал" вполне могут получить непосредственно результат (например, на бумаге).

Answer (score 1):

Тест не положительный, а нейтральный, а по нему уже будет определяться то, какой результат (отрицательный или положительный). Верным "*положительный тест*" будет, только если это название теста.

Правильно так:
*Сдать тест (как?) положительно.* || Это лучше всего подходит для тестирования (экзамена).

Более предпочтительно: *пройти тест*.

Answer (score -1):

Учитывая, что два слова из фразы заимствованные, в разговорной речи, мне кажется, допустимо использовать эту форму ;)